# Shell Extension in C# with .Net 2.0/3.0/3.5

Tags: c#-2.0

Is it Possible to develop the(shell Extention Program in C#) CSShellExtContextMenuHandler  Shell context menu handler (C#) through dot net framework 2.0/3.0/3.5. 
Because I am converting the VC++ code to C#, In VC++ through COM(ATL Project) are used but in C# those functionality is not available.

Note: Dot net framework 4.0 or above I can't use.

Please suggest me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Long standing advice was not to, e.g. "Because shell extensions are loaded into arbitrary processes and because managed code built against one version of the runtime may not run in a process running an earlier version of the runtime, Microsoft recommends against writing managed shell extensions and does not consider them a supported scenario". Some of that advice *seemed* to shift with the release of 4 (which then started to support side by side), but I believe it's still felt to be a little risky even then.

Comment: Very, very bad idea.  You'll have lots of seriously pissed-off customers whose extensions you killed and you can't help them.  Stick with your ATL solution.